# Search string inside case statement for existence of specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL, including a `CASE` statement for `D.TIN_TYPE`. I want to modify the `CASE` statement (or use an alternative) to add onto the 2nd WHEN condition so that `WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND` there is a comma (,) within the `D.PAYEE_NAME1` string then break the name into two columns using LEFT/CHARINDEX, RIGHT/CHARINDEX function, Otherwise just display the string as-is (if there is not a comma contained in the string). The column is not consistently formatted as *Lastname, Firstname* (some are *Firstname Lastname*) so that is why I need to check for the existence of the comma in the string. How can I accomplish this?

```
    SELECT D.PAYER_TIN, '001', YEAR( (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PYMNT_DT,121))), D.PAYEE_TIN, 
    CASE WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN '001' 
         WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' THEN '002' 
         END AS 'Taxpayer Identification Type', 
    A.VENDOR_ID,
    CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, 30)
         WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND --Additional logic for existence of comma--
         ELSE D.PAYEE_NAME1
         END AS 'PAYEE_NAME1', 
    D.PAYEE_NAME1,
    D.PAYEE_NAME2,  
    D.PAYEE_ADDRESS1, 
    LEFT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP,CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-1), 
    SUBSTRING(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)+2, 2), 
    RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7), 
    'US', 
    D.WTHD_BOX1, 
    D.WTHD_BOX2, 
    D.WTHD_BOX3, 
   FROM PS_WTHD_TRXN_TBL A, PS_TMP_1099_COPYB D, PS_GHS_1099_PA_VW2 E 
   WHERE ( A.WTHD_TYPE = D.WTHD_TYPE 
         AND A.VENDOR_ID = D.VENDOR_ID 
         AND YEAR( A.PYMNT_DT) = '2018')
   GROUP BY  D.PAYER_TIN,  YEAR( (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PYMNT_DT,121))),  D.PAYEE_TIN,  CASE WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN '001' 
    WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' THEN '002' 
    END,  A.VENDOR_ID,  D.PAYEE_NAME1,  D.PAYEE_NAME2,   D.PAYEE_ADDRESS1, 
    LEFT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP,CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-1),  
    SUBSTRING(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)+2, 2),  
    RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7), 
    D.WTHD_BOX1,  D.WTHD_BOX2,  D.WTHD_BOX3,  D.WTHD_BOX6,  D.WTHD_BOX7,  D.WTHD_BOX14,  D.WTHD_BOX16,  D.WTHD_BOX18
    , CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, 30)
         ELSE D.PAYEE_NAME1
         END
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the edited SQL, using an extra WHEN in the CASE statement. It runs but for the last name column (RIGHT function) it's returning both the first and last name. How can I just return the last name (characters before the comma)? Also I tried using END AS 'First Name' and END AS 'Last Name' for each WHEN but I got a syntax error. Is there a way to give the columns distinct names?

```
SELECT D.PAYER_TIN, '001', 13679089, YEAR( (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PYMNT_DT,121))), D.PAYEE_TIN, 
CASE WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN '001' 
     WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' THEN '002' 
     END AS 'Taxpayer Identification Type', 
A.VENDOR_ID,
CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, 30)
     WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1,CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)-1)  --END AS 'First Name'
     WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN RIGHT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)+1 ) --END AS 'Last Name'
     ELSE D.PAYEE_NAME1
     END AS 'PAYEE_NAME1', 
D.PAYEE_NAME1,
D.PAYEE_NAME2,  
D.PAYEE_ADDRESS1, 
LEFT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP,CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-1), 
SUBSTRING(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)+2, 2), 
RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7), 
'US', 
D.WTHD_BOX1, 
D.WTHD_BOX2, 
D.WTHD_BOX3, 
D.WTHD_BOX6, 
D.WTHD_BOX7, 
D.WTHD_BOX14, 
D.WTHD_BOX16, 
D.WTHD_BOX18 
FROM PS_WTHD_TRXN_TBL A, PS_TMP_1099_COPYB D, PS_GHS_1099_PA_VW2 E 
WHERE ( A.WTHD_TYPE = D.WTHD_TYPE 
     AND A.VENDOR_ID = D.VENDOR_ID 
     AND YEAR( A.PYMNT_DT) = '2018'
     AND A.WTHD_CLASS IN ('01','02','07') 
     AND A.VENDOR_ID = E.VENDOR_ID 
     AND A.VNDR_LOC = E.VNDR_LOC 
     AND E.YEAR = '2018' 
     AND D.WTHD_CNTL_ID = 'TGC' 
     AND D.WTHD_BOX18 > 0.00
     AND A.VENDOR_ID <> '80577A' ) 
GROUP BY  D.PAYER_TIN,  YEAR( (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PYMNT_DT,121))),  D.PAYEE_TIN,  CASE WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN '001' 
WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' THEN '002' 
END,  A.VENDOR_ID,  D.PAYEE_NAME1,  D.PAYEE_NAME2,   D.PAYEE_ADDRESS1, 
LEFT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP,CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-1),  
SUBSTRING(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)+2, 2),  
RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7), 
D.WTHD_BOX1,  D.WTHD_BOX2,  D.WTHD_BOX3,  D.WTHD_BOX6,  D.WTHD_BOX7,  D.WTHD_BOX14,  D.WTHD_BOX16,  D.WTHD_BOX18
, CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, 30)
     ELSE D.PAYEE_NAME1
     END, 
       CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, 30)
       WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1,CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)-1)  --END AS 'First Name'
       WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN RIGHT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)+1 ) --END AS 'Last Name'
       ELSE D.PAYEE_NAME1
       END
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `CASE` can return two columns, so if there's a better function that supports outputting into two columns (using the comma as delimiter) when the above conditions (TIN_TYPE = 'S' and there is a Comma in the string) are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create multiple case statements for this. My suggestion would be to create 3 case statements: one for the non-split, one for the first split and one for the second split.

To check for the comma, you can use something like this:

```
select 
    split1=case
        WHEN CHARINDEX(',','a,b') > 0 AND D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' THEN left('a,b', CHARINDEX(',','a,b')-1)
    END,
    split2=case
        WHEN CHARINDEX(',','a,b') > 0 AND D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' THEN right('a,b', len('a,b')-CHARINDEX(',','a,b'))
    END  

Results:
split1  split2
a        b
```

See [CASE (Transact-SQL) Example B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**EDIT:**
Try this shorter query taken from your edited one.  Get this to work and then start adding on the rest of your conditionals in the GROUP BY, I think that is where your problem is.

See what I did with PAYEE_FULLNAME, PAYEE_FIRSTNAME, PAYEE_LASTNAME.

```
    SELECT D.PAYER_TIN, '001', 13679089, YEAR( (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PYMNT_DT,121))), D.PAYEE_TIN, 
CASE WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN '001' 
     WHEN  D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' THEN '002' 
     END AS 'Taxpayer Identification Type', 
A.VENDOR_ID,
PAYEE_FULLNAME=CASE 
        WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, 30)
        ELSE D.PAYEE_NAME1
     END , 
PAYEE_FIRSTNAME=CASE 
        WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1,CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)-1)  --END AS 'First Name'
       END ,
PAYEE_LASTNAME=CASE 
        WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN RIGHT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)+1 ) --END AS 'Last Name'
     END
FROM PS_WTHD_TRXN_TBL A, PS_TMP_1099_COPYB D, PS_GHS_1099_PA_VW2 E 
WHERE ( A.WTHD_TYPE = D.WTHD_TYPE 
     AND A.VENDOR_ID = D.VENDOR_ID 
     AND YEAR( A.PYMNT_DT) = '2018'
     AND A.WTHD_CLASS IN ('01','02','07') 
     AND A.VENDOR_ID = E.VENDOR_ID 
     AND A.VNDR_LOC = E.VNDR_LOC 
     AND E.YEAR = '2018' 
     AND D.WTHD_CNTL_ID = 'TGC' 
     AND D.WTHD_BOX18 > 0.00
     AND A.VENDOR_ID <> '80577A' )
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I edited the post above with your suggestion, however I am still getting the first name substring in the 2nd (last name) column...Also I wanted to know if I can call each column a distinct name?

Comment: @Nick You need to follow the example I provided, one case statement per name part.  You cannot have 3 WHEN conditions in one case statement if you want to extract the name into separate fields.  That's why I labeled the first case statement Split1 and the second, Split2.

Comment: I have a syntax error even though I followed your example: `A.VENDOR_ID,
split1= CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'F' THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, 30) END ,
split2= CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN LEFT(D.PAYEE_NAME1,CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)-1) END ,   
split3= CASE WHEN D.TIN_TYPE = 'S' AND CHARINDEX(',',D.PAYEE_NAME1) > 0 THEN RIGHT(D.PAYEE_NAME1, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', D.PAYEE_NAME1)+1 )  
     ELSE D.PAYEE_NAME1
     END AS 'PAYEE_NAME1', `

Comment: Thanks Jon. Works as expected!

Comment: @Nick I'm glad it worked.  I was thinking I should have also specified my example was from SQL Server 2012.